# IIS6 vs IIS7 performance comparison

Tags: iis-7, performance, iis-6

Are there any graphs or analytics about the performance comparison of switching from IIS6 to IIS7?  I would like to convince my client to switch to Server 2008 IIS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some info in [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150694.aspx) at iis.net and some more info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284895/why-migrate-from-iis6-to-iis7) stackoverflow thread.

Additionally [ezinearticles](http://ezinearticles.com/?Benefits-of-Running-IIS7-Over-IIS6-Or-Apache&id=2131887) covers some  of the benefits as well.

Comment: I wish there was a better article.  The stackoverflow thread is just their observation.  It would be nice if someone actually gave real stats.

Comment: I couldn't find any better sadly, there are some articles that compares IIS (as a general) against Apache and Nginx etc. but those don't seem to distinguish between IIS 6, 7 and 7.5